# Holding classes in Dictionary

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I have a question about holding a class in dictionary.So I am working on a project about a university.There are more than one faculty names.When user types a faculty name,I am directing user to appropriate faculty class with using context.call

So in here,if user enters show me computer engineering,user directed to the ShowComp class.

But using if-else makes code really unreadable.I thought that I can put these keywords to dictionary

But this time context.Call gives an error about the value type.What should I put dictionary value type.I couldn't figure it out.Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Dialogs inherit from `IDialog<object>`, you can put that in the dictionary:

```
private readonly Dictionary<string, IDialog<object>> options 
      = new Dictionary<string, IDialog<object>>
        { { "computer", new ShowComp() }, { "law", new ShowLaw() } };

public async Task GetFacilities(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    var entity = result.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => options.ContainsKey(e.Entity));

    if (entity != null)
    {
        IDialog<object> dialog = null;
        if (options.TryGetValue(entity.Entity, out dialog))
        {
            context.Call(dialog, this.AfterResume);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
        static Dictionary<String, Type> FACULTY_CLASS_MAP;


        /**
         * faculty class mapping.
        */
        FACULTY_CLASS_MAP= new Dictionary<String, Type>
        {
            { "Text", typeof(FacultyClass) }
        }
```

Comment: Not use object map, if you use class, should do IDialog option =(IDialog<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(options[option_from_query], new object[] {  }), Context.Call(option, after...).
Or else well  Context.Call(options[option_from_query], after...). It is a error of programming